# Is there a GUI to see contents of .npy file?

Tags: python, numpy, save

I am working with Python 2.

I have saved a `dict` of `arrays` to a `.npy` file on my computer. If I open it as a text file, a just see a mess of ASCII characters, as one would expect since I am not *just* saving arrays.

I can see its contents by `np.load` it in a Python console, but I was wondering whether there is a GUI that allows me to see the contents of the file directly, i.e. without going through a python console?

Basically: If I went back, I would save it as a `json` or `hdf5` file so that I can open them with some viewer and could clearly see the data. 
 Having **not** done that, and having saved `.npy` files, can I see its contents in a similar way if they were json or hdf5?

Comment: The `.npy` format is a binary data format, so even if your arrays contained only numerical data it would still appear as garbage values to a text editor.  If you want to save data in a human readable format use `np.savetxt`.

Comment: Working on a solution for you that uses PySimpleGUI as the GUI.  There are already demos that display CSV and panda files so it should be possible... maybe...

Comment: A contributor has completed a simple numpy table viewer, however, it uses Python 3 and you've clearly stated you're using Python 2 so I won't post it as an answer.  This is perhaps an option if you can upgrade to 3.  If you could supply a sample numpy file we can check to see if it displays correctly in the viewer.

Comment: The contents of the .npy file, when I open it as `np.load(file)[()]` are: `{0: [array([0])],
 1: [array([1]), array([-1])],
 2: [array([2]), array([-2])],
 3: [array([3]), array([-3])],
 4: [array([4]), array([-4])],
 5: [array([5]), array([-5])],
 6: [array([6]), array([-6])],
 7: [array([7]), array([-7])],
 8: [array([8]), array([-8])],
 9: [array([9]), array([-9])],
 10: [array([10]), array([-10])],
 11: [array([11]), array([-11])],
 12: [array([12]), array([-12])],
 13: [array([13]), array([-13])],}`

Comment: Can you post your npy file or one similar?  I've got a numpy file viewer working and want to check to make sure your data will work with it.

Comment: How do I post a file here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.load` (or a clone) is the only why to load a `npy`:

```
In [84]: adict = {'a':np.arange(3), 'b':np.ones((2,3),int)}
In [85]: np.save('foo.npy',adict)
In [86]: np.load('foo.npy')
Out[86]: 
array({'a': array([0, 1, 2]), 'b': array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])}, dtype=object)
```

Note that the dictionary has been wrapped in an 0d object dtype array.  The dictionary structure was then `pickled`.  And arrays with the dictionary were pickled with `np.save` format.  Both a dictionary and an object dtype array can contain pointers to other Python objects, which need their own pickling method.  In other words, it's Python all the way down!.

If you'd attempted to use `json` you'd have found that numpy arrays are not json serializable.  You would have had to apply `tolist()` to turn the arrays into lists.  `json` just saves dictionaries, lists and strings (basic javascript structures that many languages share).  There may also be a third party serializer to numpy arrays.

`h5` is written in C++, with lots of language interfaces.  `h5dump` is a handy viewer.  But to write the dictionary from your Python dictionary you'd have to use `h5py` (or `pytables`).  A dictionary maps nicely onto h5 groups, and numpy arrays to h5 datasets.

Answer (score 6):

I think this tool can help you do what you need. It can help you edit the contents of .npy files like spreadsheets. It also has options to visualize .npy files as 2D grayscale images and 3D point clouds:

https://github.com/csmailis/NPYViewer

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no GUI capable of reading the contents of `.npy` as plain text. However, if you think that such a program would be beneficial to the community, then you can easily create such a tool.

Let's look at a couple ways in which the aforementioned tool could work:

1. Simply output the results of `np.load` to a file using the console command:

   `$ python your_program.py > file.txt`

   This redirects the console output from `your_program.py` to `file.txt`.
2. Use the `contextlib.redirect_stdout()` function to output only a the relevant data from `stdout` into `file.txt`.

Like so:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
    with open("help.txt", "w") as f:
         with redirect_stdout(f):
             print('it now prints to 'help.text')
```